# Excel to SQL mapping tool

Tags: .net, microsoft-excel, sql, sql-server, asp.net

I am looking for a tool/library to import data from different clients into our SQL database. Each client will have their own EXCEL file. So the number of columns, name of the columns in EXCEL would be different for each client. But the data from these excel files will end up in our SQL database into predefined SQL tables.
So basically I am looking for mapping tool that maps excel column to SQL column, and then import it. Client should also be able to defined default values for a particular column mapping. ( Defining custom rules for each column would be a plus)
My application is developed in ASP.NET MVC. My preference would be to integrate this tool/library with-in the application. However I am also open for separate application preferably web based

Anyone know?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: no i did not. I used homegrown solution

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Is it open-source or commercially available for sale?