# Tool that guides converting / mapping JSON, XML, Excel based data to various SQL Table Formats

Tags: database, microsoft-excel, sql, mapping

I would hope this tool would let me select columns for import from excel and then rigidly apply data type rules, allow custom conversion functions, and provide some sort of "workflow" that retains the history of parallel and sequential actions.

Currently I am using Microsoft power query... but I fear what I would use besides custom C#.NET programming if I had to do larger datasets.

Found this link, [Excel to SQL mapping tool](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50536/excel-to-sql-mapping-tool)

But... also no answers. I'm under the impression this software doesn't exist. 
Usually the import tools in database software are not very forgiving on data format expectations.

Comment: Reading between the lines: you want software that runs on Windows, and doesn't cost more than USD 1.000 (monthly subscription)?

Comment: Depending on the software I would pay and use a different OS, ha!